# Oracle Function With - IF EXISTS -

Tags: oracle, plsql

How I do ***if exists*** in Oracle? In SQL Server the following works.

```
create or replace FUNCTION FExemplo(p_processoId INT) RETURN varchar2
AS
  v_Result varchar2(255);
  v_TemIsso INT;
BEGIN
  v_TemIsso := 0;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT EXEMPLO.EXEMPLOID FROM EXEMPLO WHERE EXEMPLO.EXEMPLOID = p_processoId)
  THEN
    v_TemIsso := 1;
  END IF;
  RETURN '';
END FExemplo;
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot simply copy code from _SQL Server_ to _Oracle_. You need to learn the _Oracle_ way of doing things. If you haven't already done so, I suggest reading the _PL/SQL Language Reference_ which is part of the _Oracle_ database documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable for counting elements like this:

```
SELECT count(EXEMPLO.EXEMPLOID) into v_count FROM EXEMPLO WHERE EXEMPLO.EXEMPLOID = 
p_processoId

 IF v_count > 0 THEN 
    --do something
 ELSE 
    --do something
 END IF;
```

Of course, you have to define the variable `v_count` as a number before you use it.

If you do not use the `v_count` variable you can get a exception like `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

Answer (score 0):

The `IF EXISTS` syntax is not allowed in PL/SQL. You could rewrite your code so it uses `EXISTS` within a query instead, like so:

```
BEGIN
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM EXEMPLO 
        WHERE EXEMPLO.EXEMPLOID = p_processoId
    ) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    INTO v_TemIsso
FROM DUAL;
-- rest of your code follows
END
```